# How to insert multiple elements into one element via append in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am very confused as to why only the last element is inserted when I try to append multiple elements within a for loop.

I have created a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k0pernikus/U9swZ/) showcasing my inability to get it to work. I expect 100 anchor tags to  be inserted, yet only the last element is inserted.

---

For posterior's sake, here's the relevant JavaScript, the TODO marks the relevant part:

```
Math.randomNumber = function(max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * max % max);
}


var Door = {
    $el: $('<a>', {
        class: 'door selectable'
    }),
    number: null,
    isSelected: false,
    containsZonk: true,
    bind: function () {
        var that = this;
        this.$el.on('click tap', function () {
            that.isSelected = true
        });
    }
}

var Platform = {
    $el: null,
    doorCount: null,
    jackpotNumber: null,
    doors: [],
    init: function($el, doorCount) {
        this.$el = $el;
        this.doorCount = doorCount;

        for (var i = 0; i <= doorCount - 1; i++) {
            var door = Object.create(Door);
            door.number = i;
            door.$el.html(i.toString());
            this.doors.push(door);

            /* TODO: wtf why is only last one inserted? */
            this.$el.append(door.$el);
        }

        this.jackpotNumber = Math.randomNumber(doorCount);
        this.doors[this.jackpotNumber].containsZonk = false;
    }
}
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var platform = Object.create(Platform);
        var $game = $('.door_game');
        platform.init($game, 100);
    });
```

I want to insert all 100 elements into `div.door_game`:

```
<body>
    <h1>Zonk!</h1>
        <div class="door_game" data-doors="10">
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: you probably need to change `Math.round(Math.random() * 100 % 100)` to `Math.round(Math.random() * max % max)`

Comment: @razzak Yeah, I noticed that too while preparing the question yet it was not necessary to fix for the my real problem. Thanks for pointing it out nonetheless though.

Comment: also this doesn't make sense `this.doors[this.jackpotNumber].containsZonk = true;` when all `door` objects have this property `containsZonk: true,`! you may wanna change it to `cotainsZonk: false,`?

Comment: @razzak Yeah, you are right once again. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because all your doors are sharing the same `$el`.

http://jsfiddle.net/U9swZ/9/

```
var Door = {
    number: null,
    isSelected: false,
    containsZonk: true,
    bind: function () {
        var that = this;
        this.$el.on('click tap', function () {
            that.isSelected = true
        });
    },
    init: function () {
        this.$el = $('<a>', {
            class: 'door selectable'
        });
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Door $el is created once and that's why it is appended and appended again (i.e. moved again and again) so that you only see the last one. @plalx is right about it.

Morever, something very important since you append hundreds of doors, use a documentFragment (`var frag = document.createDocumentFragment()`) before the loop, to gather you doors (`frag.appendChild(...)`) and append this documentFragment to the Platform $el after the loop (`this.$el.appendChild(frag)`). The performance gain is very important with such amounts of elements.

And, don't hesitate to clone an element instead of rebuilding it. It 's much more faster. You can even use the DOM API `cloneNode(false)` method to do a not in depth copy of the original element.

Comment: My focus wasn't on performance when answering, but that's definitely a best practice. It's good you mentionned it. +1

Comment: I do not want to be overly nitpicky, but this is more of a comment than an answer to the question. I do value the insight, so I'll give you +1 anyway.

Comment: I took the liberty to add an example and compared the times. Thank you for teaching me about the concept :)

Comment: My edit was rejected. Maybe you want to introduce an implementation within your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1919574